# Contacting Pulse Audio over dbus?

Tags: pulseaudio, ruby, dbus

I am trying to write a basic volume application. Since I'm writing this in Ruby I don't want to extend the C library or use `ffi`, instead I trying to write this with `ruby-dbus` I got the `Address` Property with `/org/pulse_audio/server_lookup1` but the file the address points to doesn't exist. Is Pulse Audio properly configured for `dbus`?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the DBus Module was not loaded.

if you're using Ruby you can call:

```
%x{pacmd load-module module-dbus-protocol}
```

Works on the command line too:

```
pacmd load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

Answer (score 0):

I think /org/pulse_audio/server_lookup1 is an internal path for PulseAudio's ServerLookup1 Object.  You will not find this "file" in your computer's directory.